# com.sun.jdi.VMDisconnectedException: connection is closed

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, memory-leaks, exception

I was doing load testing on weblogic server.Messages were exchanged alot and some network congestion has also been seen as i was getting timeout responses.

After some time, I received "**com.sun.jdi.VMDisconnectedException: connection is closed**" exception.

May i know the reason of this exception.This exception means,,,Connection has been lost to target VM but whats the reason.

I think due to network congestion but not sure.

Please help and provide explanation.